# Is $k$-sum larger than the square of $2$ - norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

the $k$-sum, denoted as $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{[k]}$, is defined as the sum of $k$ absolutely largest elements of $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Suppose $\boldsymbol{x}\in[0,1]^n$ and $\boldsymbol{1}^\top\boldsymbol{x}=c$ for any integer $c$ less than $n$.  Is it true that $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{[c]}\geq \boldsymbol{x}^\top\boldsymbol{x}$?

I intuitively feel it is right and I did't find any counter - example for $n=3,c=2$ using MATLAB.

Could anyone provide some hints or ideas to prove it or disprove it?

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistency, I have modified it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dumbed-down version of ronno's answer. Without loss of generality we may assume that $1\geq x_1\geq\cdots\geq x_n\geq 0$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^c x_i^2 + x_c\sum_{i=c+1}^n x_i\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^c x_i^2 + x_c\left(c-\sum_{i=1}^c x_i\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^c x_i^2 + x_c\sum_{i=1}^c(1-x_i)\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^c x_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^cx_i(1-x_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^c x_i.\\
\end{aligned}

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. In fact
$$||\mathbf{x}||_{[c]} = \max \{ \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{y} \in [0,1]^n, \mathbf{1}^\top \mathbf{y} = c\} .$$
Now it suffices to take $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x}$.

This equality can be proved directly by reasoning similar to that in @RamenNii-chan's answer, but here is a different argument. The set
$$S = \{\mathbf{y} \in [0,1]^n \mid \mathbf{1}^\top \mathbf{y} = c\} $$
is compact, since $\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{y} = c$ is a closed condition on the compact set $[0,1]^n$. So there is some (not necessarily unique) $\mathbf{y} \in S$ that achieves the maximum. We will show that for any $\mathbf{y} \in S$, either $\mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{x} = || \mathbf{x}||_{[c]}$ or there is some $\mathbf{y}' \in S$ for which $\mathbf{y}'^\top \mathbf{x} > \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{x}$. Suppose $\mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{x} \ne || \mathbf{x}||_{[c]}$. Then there are some $1 \le i, j \le n$ such that $y_i < 1$, $y_j > 0$ and $x_j > x_i$. Now it suffices to take $\mathbf{y}'$ with $y_i' = y_i + \varepsilon$, $y_j' = y_j - \varepsilon$ (and other $y_k' = y_k$) for $\varepsilon$ small, eg $\varepsilon = \min(1 -y_i, y_j)$.

Thus for any $\mathbf{y} \in S$ that does achieve the maximum, $\mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{x} = ||\mathbf{x}||_{[c]}$.

Comment: thank you! but I'm a little confused about how to obtain the variational form on the right-hand side. Would you mind giving some explanation or reference?

Comment: @ZangSan added an argument using compactness, let me know if any of the details are unclear or if you prefer the more direct argument I allude to.

Answer (score 1):

(This is basically a rewrite of ronno’s answer for my own reference. I post it here simply because it may be rude to edit ronno’s answer substantially.)

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be the linear functional $f(\mathbf{y})=\mathbf y^\top\mathbf{x}$. Then $\|\mathbf{x}\|_{[c]}=\max_{\mathbf{v}\in V}f(\mathbf{v})$ where $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of all integer vectors with $c$ entries equal to $1$ and the other $n-c$ entries equal to $0$. However, observe that $V$ is the set of all extreme points of the compact convex set
$$S = \{\mathbf{y} \in [0,1]^n \mid \mathbf{1}^\top \mathbf{y} = c\}.$$
In linear programming, it is well-known that the maximum value of a linear functional over a compact convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can always be found at an extreme point of that set. Therefore
$$\|\mathbf{x}\|_{[c]}
=\max_{\mathbf{v}\in V}f(\mathbf{v})
=\max_{\mathbf{y}\in S}f(\mathbf{y})
\ge f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{x},$$
where the last inequality is due to the fact that $\mathbf{x}\in S$.

Comment: This is actually a bit simpler than my proof, since I don't use that well-known fact (or convexity of $S$). I'm directly showing that any other point is not a (local) maximum.